# Recent records by TIME field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time

I have a simple table that has a TIME column named `timeC` in the example below. I want to select all the records for which timeC is in the last five minutes. I have tried the following and many variations without success.

```
SELECT * FROM sample_schema.`exampleTable`
WHERE MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(SELECT TIME(NOW())), `timeC`)<5;
```

Note that the column is TIME, not DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

Suggestions?

Comment: Since the `TIME` type only contains time-of-day, i.e. no idea of which date it belongs to, I'm not sure what you're trying to query, really :)

Comment: @akx, the problem is constrained such that the record being checked is always from an earlier point on the day the query is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses are in the wrong places. So you're calling `TIMEDIFF()` with 1 argument, and calling `MINUTE()` with 2 arguments. Also, you don't need to use `SELECT` to get `TIME(NOW())`, you can just use that function call as an argument.

```
SELECT *
FROM exampleTable
WHERE MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(TIME(NOW()), timeC)) < 5
```

However, there's still a problem with this. `TIMEDIFF()` can return a negative time if `timeC` is later in the day, but `MINUTE()` always returns the positive value of the minute, so this will match anything from 5 minutes ago to 5 minutes later. It would be better to simply compare the time with a range:

```
SELECT *
FROM exampleTable
WHERE timeC BETWEEN TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND TIME(NOW())
```

There's one ramaining problem. If you perform this query shortly after midnight, the time of 5 minutes earlier will be a late time from the previous day. For instance, if it's currently `00:02`, 5 minutes earlier will be `23:57`, and nothing will match the `BETWEEN` expression. You need to check for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM exampleTable
WHERE CASE 
    WHEN TIME(NOW()) >= '00:05'
        THEN timeC BETWEEN TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND TIME(NOW())
    ELSE timeC BETWEEN '00:00' AND TIME(NOW()) 
        OR
         timeC BETWEEN TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND '23:59:59'
    END
```